# ERROR starting neo4j service on ubuntu

Tags: neo4j

I installed neo4j 2.0.0 M06  version on my Ubuntu pc. It service worked fine, and I could use the new web browser perfectly.
Then, I used the sample java project (https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/blob/2.0.0-M06/community/embedded-examples/src/main/java/org/neo4j/examples/EmbeddedNeo4jWithIndexing.java)  to connect embedded way to the DB and add some nodes. (btw, I'm sure I stopped the neo4j service before launching the java application)

I changed the number of nodes added by the program to 100,000, and the application crashed on exceeding heap size (GC overhead limit).

Now, when trying to launch the neo4j I get a startup error :

```
2013-11-01 09:53:13.806+0000 DEBUG [API] Failed to start Neo Server on port [7474]
2013-11-01 10:00:52.865+0000 INFO  [API] Setting startup timeout to: 120000ms based on -1
2013-11-01 10:00:52.998+0000 DEBUG [API] 
org.neo4j.server.ServerStartupException: Starting Neo4j Server failed: org/neo4j/helpers    /Settings
    at org.neo4j.server.AbstractNeoServer.start(AbstractNeoServer.java:193) ~[neo4j-        server-2.0.0-M06.jar:2.0.0-M06]
    at org.neo4j.server.Bootstrapper.start(Bootstrapper.java:87) [neo4j-server-2.0.0-    M06.jar:2.0.0-M06]
    at org.neo4j.server.Bootstrapper.main(Bootstrapper.java:50) [neo4j-server-2.0.0-        M06.jar:2.0.0-M06]
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/neo4j/helpers/Settings
    at org.neo4j.shell.ShellSettings.<clinit>(ShellSettings.java:42) ~[neo4j-shell-        2.0.0-M06.jar:2.0.0-M06]
    at                     org.neo4j.server.database.CommunityDatabase.getDbTuningPropertiesWithServerDefaults(Communit    yDatabase.java:106) ~[neo4j-server-2.0.0-M06.jar:2.0.0-M06]
    at org.neo4j.server.enterprise.EnterpriseDatabase.start(EnterpriseDatabase.java:89)          ~[neo4j-server-enterprise-2.0.0-M06.jar:2.0.0-M06]
    at org.neo4j.server.AbstractNeoServer.start(AbstractNeoServer.java:141) ~[neo4j-        server-2.0.0-M06.jar:2.0.0-M06]
    ... 2 common frames omitted
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.neo4j.helpers.Settings
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366) ~[na:1.7.0_45]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355) ~[na:1.7.0_45]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_45]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354) ~[na:1.7.0_45]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425) ~[na:1.7.0_45]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358) ~[na:1.7.0_45]
    ... 6 common frames omitted
2013-11-01 10:00:53.000+0000 DEBUG [API] Failed to start Neo Server on port [7474]
```

Comment: you somehow messed up your classpath, ClassNotFoundException on org.neo4j.helpers.Settings means that neo4j-kernel-2.0.0-M06.jar is not on the classpath.

Comment: Check the files in your lib folder - you should see neo4j-kernel-2.0.0-M06.jar as Stefan mentioned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem with the jar files. Unfortunately, after solving the jar files problem, I had to reinstall neo4j for the service to work again